# R reverse counter of resets to time to reset

Tags: arrays, r, sorting, reverse

Hi I have a data frame

Input : Data$cyclesFromLastError

That rests every time an error occurred.

Input:

```
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

And I want to create new column 
Output: Data$cyclesToNextError

```
4 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

I need the script for that please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ave`, create groups at every occurrence of 0 in `x` and `rev`erse the sequence for each group.

```
ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = rev)
#[1] 4 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

**data**

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```